# Reference sibling targets in Grunt config

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt build task that I've registered that has a few tasks in it (clean, concat, etc.)

```
var target = grunt.option('target') || 'local';
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:' +  target, 'copy:' + target]);

// execute the build task
grunt build --target=dev
```

Some of the tasks have local/dev/prod targets that are distinct from each other, while other tasks may just have the prod target being different.

```
clean: {
    local: { ... },
    dev: this.local, // same as local
    prod: { /* different from local */ }
},
concat: {
    local: { ... },
    dev: { /* different from local */ },
    prod: { /* different from local */ }
}
```

Referencing `this.local` for `clean.dev` target throws an error

> Verifying property clean.dev exists in config...ERROR

`clean` is an object literal so I should be able to just reference `this.local`. Not sure why that's failing.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is definitely a duh moment for me.

At the point of the object literal creation, `this` has no value. If dev were a function and `this` was referenced in the function then everything would be fine. JavaScript 101 right.

So to give `this` a value I just newed an immediate function for the object representing `clean`

```
clean: new (function() {
    this.local = { ... },
    this.dev = this.local, // same as local
    this.prod = { /* different from local */ }
})()
```

And now it works as expected.